# How can I secure the use of my dll by other applications

Tags: c#, wpf

I made some UI controls by WPF and wrap it into a DLL.

As we know, everyone can reference the DLL easily but I don't want it being like that.

I want only the program which I made to use it.

In my opinion, I think I can add something such a password when the user creates the control. However, I don't know if it is a good idea.

I want to know more about that. Would you please tell me? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps obfuscating your dll will help https://freeobfuscator.com/

Comment: @Avi Seems doubtful since an obfuscator is unlikely to obfuscate public interfaces.

Comment: @AviMeltser obfuscating  is just to prevent someone to copy your source code but not using your dll directly.

Comment: @John Yes, the public interfaces is just what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a license key or some form of token that needs to be passed to some method in your DLL to allow any subsequent calls to be made. Without the license key, your controls could be set to some evaluation mode, or just totally disabled. It's really up to you.

Maybe browse some sites of companies that do this for a living like DevExpress or any number of other companies that make user control libraries and get a feel for the types of ways they ensure people license their products prior to use.

I realise your requirement may not be around licensing, but you could still restrict access via a similar mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscating only obscures your source code. What you're actually looking for is [.NET Code Access Security](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5724/Understanding-NET-Code-Access-Security) ... the linked article demonstrates how to ensure that the calling code has the right permissions to use your code.

This solution however doesn't stop anyone from decompiling your source code and just copying it over bypassing your security (from what I can tell with a quick skim through anyway) so using a combination of obfuscation and implementing code access security might be your best bet.

Using passwords when a user creates your controls also isn't going to work, you can't implement it in that fashion, instead, the person using your controls will need to possess a valid digital signature to use it.

Comment: I think not only need the obfuscating but also need the access permission which the link showed. However, the content of the link published in 2004 and seems using something third-party old tools to do it. I wonder if there is some new ways to do this? Thank you.

Comment: What's more, there are some third-party commercial custom control libraries. I wonder how they manage access permission.